# Rails 3 Object#try not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Where should I start looking?  Here's what makes me believe that:

```
0 urzatron work/secret_project % rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.1.3)

irb(main):001:0> t = Tag.new(:name => "!Blark!")
=> #<Tag id: nil, name: "!Blark!", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>

irb(main):002:0> t.try(:name)
=> "!Blark!"

irb(main):003:0> t.try(:aoeu)
NoMethodError: undefined method `aoeu' for #<Tag id: nil, name: "!Blark!", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activemodel-3.1.3/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:385:in `method_missing'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:60:in `method_missing'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:32:in `try'
        from (irb):3
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:45:in `start'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:40:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

The `Tag` model:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :taggings, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're misunderstanding what `try` does. From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try):

> **try(*a, &b)**
>   Invokes the method identified by the symbol `method`, passing it any arguments and/or the block specified, just like the regular Ruby `Object#send` does.
>
> Unlike that method however, a `NoMethodError` exception will **not** be raised and `nil` will be returned instead, if the receiving object is a `nil` object or NilClass.

So doing this:

```
t.try(:aoeu)
```

is more or less the same as this:

```
t.nil?? nil : t.aoeu
```

but you seem to be expecting it to behave like this:

```
t.respond_to?(:aoeu) ? t.aoeu : nil
```

Your `t` isn't `nil` so `t.try(:aoeu)` is the same as `t.aoeu`. Your Tag class doesn't have an `aoeu` method so you get a `NoMethodError`.

`try` is just a convenient way of avoiding a `nil` check, it isn't a way to avoid a `NoMethodError` when the object doesn't respond to the method you're trying to use.