# Rails 3.2 Obj.try() failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I just upgraded from Rails 3.1.0 to 3.2.3.  Once I got my gem dependency issues cleared up I managed to run tests and I discovered this:

```
1.9.2p180 :005 > Rails.version
 => "3.2.3" 
1.9.2p180 :006 > a = 'test'
 => "test" 
1.9.2p180 :007 > a.try(:banana)
NoMethodError: undefined method `banana' for "test":String
    from /Users/jamesthullbery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@app_tier/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib    /active_support/core_ext/object/try.rb:32:in `try'
    from (irb):7
    from /Users/jamesthullbery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@app_tier/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails    /commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/jamesthullbery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@app_tier/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/jamesthullbery/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@app_tier/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
1.9.2p180 :008 >
```

When I perform the same command on Rails 3.1.0 I get no issues:

```
1.9.2p180 :004 >   Rails.version
 => "3.1.0" 
1.9.2p180 :005 > a = 'test'
 => "test" 
1.9.2p180 :006 > a.try(:banana)
 => nil 
1.9.2p180 :007 >
```

Has anyone seen this issue?  Certainly there is something wrong with my environment and not the Rails framework.  It seems to be pretty difficult to accurately search for the method try, so I haven't found anything online yet.  Is anyone else seeing this?  Thanks!

Comment: some one already posted this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697235/rails-3-objecttry-not-working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object#try` is supposed to deal with nil receivers. It should not be used to avoid `NoMethodError` exceptions.

The behavior you saw in 3.1.0 was a bug and [it was "fixed" 7 months ago](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/82d41c969897cca28bb318f7caf301d520a2fbf3) (as of this writing).

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was just diving into the source code and found myself on that commit you linked too.  Suppose it pays to stay on top of the Rails updates, would have caught this much sooner.